# meaning of setCursor(X,Y) coordinates

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, lcd

This example sketch shows how to use the setCursor() method to reposition the cursor. To move the cursor, just call setCursor() with a row and column position. For example, for a 2x16 display:

```cpp
lcd.setCursor(0, 0); // top left
lcd.setCursor(15, 0); // top right
lcd.setCursor(0, 1); // bottom left
lcd.setCursor(15, 1); // bottom right
```

I am not able to understand the above code.Can anyone please give the clarification for the same?

Answer (score 6):

The line `lcd.setCursor()` moves the cursor. The cursor is the position of the lertter you want the text to begin displaying at. `lcd.setCursor()` takes two values: an `x` position and a `y` position. It takes them in this order: `lcd.setCursor(x, y)`.

A `2x16` display means that it has 2 rows and 16 columns of characters, or 2 `y` values and 16 `x` values.

In Arduino code and in most c-type languages you start counting at 0, this means that to get the first column you need to tell the Arduino to look at `x` of 0. Or to put a letter in the last column on the first row you would need to tell the Arduino to move the cursor to: `(15, 0)`.

#### Example Display

The display will look like this:

[image]